# Error message while using git rebase in iterm2

Tags: git, oh-my-zsh

Recently, I got a warning message while updating oh my zsh,

```
Updating Oh My Zsh
fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge"
 and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.

There was an error updating. Try again later?
 ~  cd kimono                                                              ✔
  ~/kimono  master  git rebase --skip                                      ✔
fatal: No rebase in progress?
 ~/kimono  master  git rebase --quit                                  128 ✘
 fatal: No rebase in progress?
 ~/kimono  master 
```

As you can see there is no rebase in progress. Moreover I also tried, `rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge"` but of no help. May I get some advice on how to fix it. I am hesitating to do a `hard reset`, because it seems not to be advised so much.

Also ran `git status` as part of ebugging

```
 ~/kimono  master  git status                                             ✔
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

 nothing to commit, working tree clean

 ~/kimono  master  git rebase --abort                                     ✔
 fatal: No rebase in progress?
 ~/kimono  master 
```

Comment: What is the output of `git rebase --abort`?  Also can you add the output of `git status` to your question?

Comment: @Andy J Please see my edits above.